# SOLVED Can't install the latest adb version on Rasperry Pi OS 64 bit Bullseye

Tags: android, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, 64-bit

I need to install the latest adb tool on a Rasperry Pi OS 64 bit Bullseye.

The adb version I get from apt-get install adb is too old (Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 28.0.2-debian) as i'm using the "adb pair" command available only on 30.0 and more.

I've tried to download the Platform tools from https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools but when I run adb I get "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

I don't really understand as it seems that adb is a 64bit exec (objdump -a ./adb gives elf64-little) but i'm not expert in this.

Is there anyone who knows how to run this latest version of adb or any other way ?

Thanks a lot !

Olivier

EDIT 08/24/23 : I have found these [binaries](https://github.com/lzhiyong/android-sdk-tools/releases) (via [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545278/install-build-tools-on-arm64-doesnt-work)). I just downloaded [these files](https://github.com/lzhiyong/android-sdk-tools/releases/download/33.0.3/android-sdk-tools-static-aarch64.zip) and I got adb version 33.0.3 running on Raspbian). Thanks everyone !

Comment: Those are compiled for 64-bit x86 ("x86-64"), you need 64-bit for ARM8.  Two different, incompatible [ISAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture).  I'd say build it from source, but I don't think that is so feasible on a Pi as it seems you need to build Android first (also it sounds like it isn't even a preconfigured build target: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232971797).  Look around for a distro that has an arm64 port and ships with the version you want, and install that in a container.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try that then.

Comment: I actually found binaries (see EDIT)

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please close this issue.